# How can I add a class to an element on hover?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How to add class to a div when hovered on the div.

Template -

```html
<div class="red">On hover add class ".yellow"</div>
```

Component -

```js
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html',
    styles: [`
        .red {
          background: red;
        }
        
        .yellow {
          background: yellow;
     }
  `]
})
export class HelloWorld {}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/J6o3aIMXlFsrb2NOzeLt?p=preview)

[ NOTE - I specifically want to add a new class and not modify the existing classes ]

Sigh! It is such a normal use case and I do not see any straight forward solution yet!

Comment: Use a directive. Read this article and you should be able to figure out the rest :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Any reason not to just use a CSS `:hover` for this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can also just use something like:

```html
[ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)"
```

Then in the component

```js
color:string = 'red';
  
changeStyle($event){
  this.color = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'yellow' : 'red';
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pmcNdf4imYPnShnxFPUT?p=preview)

Alternatively, do everything in the markup:

```html
[ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="color='yellow'" (mouseout)="color='red'"
```

Answer (score 91):

Not to dirty the code I just coded simple `hover-class` directive.

```html
<span hover-class="btn-primary" class="btn" >Test Me</span>
```

[Running Sample](https://angular-xqeflh.stackblitz.io)

[Code Editor stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqeflh)

Here below the directive,

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[hover-class]'
})
export class HoverClassDirective {

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) { }
    @Input('hover-class') hoverClass: any;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add(this.hoverClass);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove(this.hoverClass);
    }

}
```

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlbakkar https://www.monkeyuser.com/2020/election

Answer (score 45):

Simple as below

```
<button [class.btn-success]="mouseOvered" 
  (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true"
  (mouseout)="mouseOvered=false"> Hover me </button>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xgI5jOPI9HDUJb71RfmT?p=preview)**

Comment: What if you have more than one button? You want to change the class only for the one you are hovering, not all of them. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @mario595 use a `span` tag and wrap it under a `*ngIf. if you need more info let me know

Comment: @Aravind can you please provide an example? I am finding that each button is getting the class changed instead of only the one that is hovered upon.

Comment: Can you check the plunker in the demo

Comment: your ans helped me @Aravind. Thanks

Comment: Worked perfectly. But we need to define variable mouseOvered: boolean; in .ts file.

Answer (score 2):

In case you set the styles programmatically (e.g. from an attribute in the component) and want it to change on hover, you can have a look at [this Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aNAL9z?p=preview).

It also answers the question when multiple elements have to respond to the mouseover event.

Here is the code:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <div id="1" 
      (mouseover)="showDivWithHoverStyles(1)" 
      (mouseout)="showAllDivsWithDefaultStyles()" 
      [ngStyle]="hoveredDivId ===1 ? hoveredDivStyles : defaultDivStyles">
      The first div
    </div>
    
    <div id="2" 
      (mouseover)="showDivWithHoverStyles(2)" 
      (mouseout)="showAllDivsWithDefaultStyles()" 
      [ngStyle]="hoveredDivId === 2 ? hoveredDivStyles :  defaultDivStyles">
      The second div
    </div>`
})
class App{
  hoveredDivId;
  defaultDivStyles= {height: '20px', 'background-color': 'white'};
  hoveredDivStyles= {height: '50px', 'background-color': 'lightblue'};
  
  showDivWithHoverStyles(divId: number) {
    this.hoveredDivId = divId;
  }

  showAllDivsWithDefaultStyles() {
    this.hoveredDivId = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<li *ngFor="let q of questions;let i = index" class="list-group-item" (mouseenter)="isHover = i"
    [ngClass]="{'active' : isHover === i}">
    <h5>Question 1</h5>
    <p>what is the largest man made structure on the earth ?</p>
</li>
```

`isHover` and `questions` are properties declare in the `.ts` file.

Answer (score 2):

I took Davut's example and changed it to handle multiple classes...

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[hover-class]'
})
export class HoverClassDirective {

    constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Input('hover-class') hoverClass: any;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.update('add');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.update('remove');
    }

    protected update(action: string): void {
        this.hoverClass.split(' ').forEach(item => this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList[action](item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@HostListener` decorator is also a good option if you are applying on entire component.

keep the html as it is and in the component add `@HostListener`

```html
<div class="red">On hover add class ".yellow"</div>
```

```js
@HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.class = 'red';
}
    
@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.class = 'yellow';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Shortest solution - HTML only

```
<span #newTask class="btn"
      [ngClass]="newTask.matches(':hover') ? 'btn-success': 'btn-secondary'"
      (mouseover)="''" (mouseleave)="''"
>
  New
</span>
```