# Angular 4- How to add and remove multiple classes with ngClass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am looking to create nav links that look like file folder tabs by adding and removing class with angular. When a link is active, it will not have a bottom border so it appears to be the primary tab. Here's a rough beginning:

[image]

How can I correctly use [ngClass] to add and remove classes to my links given these questions?

Problem 1: how to implement a hover directive? I want the non-active link to shade grey when hovered over

Problem 2: How to add the 'active-link' class to one of them by default, so that on initial load it appears active (no bottom border)

What I have so far-

my component.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li [ngClass]="{'active-link': id === 1 }" id="1"(click)="addClass(id=1)" ><a [routerLink]="['']" data-toggle="tab">All Sites</a></li>
 <li [ngClass]="{'active-link': id === 2 }" id="2"(click)="addClass(id=2)"><a [routerLink]="['/sites/map']" data-toggle="tab">Sites Map</a></li>    
</ul>
```

My component.css:

```
li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.active-link {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.nav li {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

And for my .ts file

```
export class AppComponent { 
  addClass(id: any) {
  this.id = id;
}
...
```

What can I change/add to my code to cleanly add the 'active-link' by default, as well as a hover directive for the non-active link?

Thanks! Let me know if I can clarify

Comment: Just set the id = the number of your default tab in ngOnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a property like `selectedTab` which is what i'm guessing `id` is doing here. Just have all tabs have the unselected/inactive class and apply the active class only if the `selectedTab`/`id` is equal to that tabs id, you don't need `ngClass` if you don't want it you can write `[class.active-link]="id === 1"` where one is that links id. Set the variable `id` to your default tab in `ngOnInit` (or in the constructor or default in the class). If I'm missing something here let me know.

As for your hover issue, [How can I add a class to an element on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633117/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-an-element-on-hover)

.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedTab = 0;

  constructor() {}
  // Function to select a tab.
  selectTab(tabId: number) {
    this.selectedTab = tabId;
  }
}
```

.html file:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li [class.active-link]="selectedTab === 0" (click)="selectTab(0)"><a data-toggle="tab">All Sites</a></li>
 <li [class.active-link]="selectedTab === 1" (click)="selectTab(1)"><a data-toggle="tab">All Sites</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'mm having a little trouble interpreting, do I need to keep id if I use 'selectedTab'? Would you mind specifying how I write that in my .ts file? Thanks

Comment: sure there's some code. And no you need only `selectedTab` OR `id` I just think `selectedTab` is more descriptive than `id` (I imagine id would be used in several places throughout the component/application).

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure if I'd need to use that id elsewhere. Very helpful thank you!