# How to use custom jquery codes in angular 6 project?

Tags: angular, angular6

This is a `jquery` code in my `HTML template`. I am using a `HTML template` and `sliced` it to different `components` and created an `angular project`.

```
   //  class add mouse hover
   jQuery('.custom-nav > li').hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).addClass('nav-hover');
   }, function(){
      jQuery(this).removeClass('nav-hover');
   });
```

> This code is not working.

The file is saved in a folder named `assets` inside `node_modules` as `scripts_custom.js`. The file is included in `angular.json`.

I am new to `angular6`. Please do help me to correct it.

Comment: why not use directive instead to add class ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CruelEngine . Actually am new to angular6. I just copied the js page to node modules and tried. Could you please give me a hind to convert this?

Comment: please have look https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633254/3769965

Comment: @RaruChempazhanthy check the above comment

Comment: Using JQuery in Angular is like equipping a ship with wheels: you can, but it doesn't mean it's useful. Maybe the movement of wheel will make your ship run, but maybe it's not how it's been designed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video helped me to solve the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlgsWcYnPdo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'frontend';
  ngOnInit(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //  class add mouse hover
    jQuery('.custom-nav > li').hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).addClass('nav-hover');
      }, function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('nav-hover');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this is a good way to solve it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

It not a good practice to include jquery in angular project but still you want to use it you can write declare $ any in component file after all import section

Please let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ankur Shah it is not good practice to use Jquery in an angular project. Instead, you can use a custom directive or use (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) event.

Check the link below [toggleclass](https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggleclass)

Answer (score 1):

To include jQuery code into your component do the following steps:

step 1: Add jQuery into your index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

step 2: Declare jQuery into your component where you want to add that code as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular 4 with jquery';
  //Add jQuery here
}
```

Hope this will work for you. Thanks