# Angular | How to define a template variable for a div

Tags: angular

The following code generates 4 200x200 divs.

I want to set a class to a div when mouse is hovering (the class should be set only to the div that is hovered, not the other three)

```
<style>
   div {height: 200px; width: 200px; margin: 20px;}
   .mouseover {background-color: red;}
</style>

<div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4]" 
    [class.mouseover]="mouseOvered" 
    (mouseover)="mouseOvered=true" 
    (mouseleave)="mouseOvered=false">
</div>
```

How can this be done without defining `mouseOvered` in the component?

Comment: If you are simply looking at simplifying or writting less code, you could isolate this logic in a directive - though I think what you have is just fine

Comment: The problem with the above solution is that all divs will get class 'mouseover' if a single div is hovered. 
I think you are right about creating a custom directive.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42633117/2050306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a directive to isolate each instance within the `ngFor`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mouseOver]'
})
export class MouseOverDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.mouseover')
  isMouseOver = false;

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onEnter() {
    this.isMouseOver = true;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  onLeave() {
    this.isMouseOver = false;
  }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4]" mouseOver></div>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvbck5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

#### Alternative

If you prefer not creating a directive, you can also use an index map to store the condition of each instance:

Component class:

```
export class MyExampleComponent  {

  mouseOvered: { [index: number]: boolean } = {};

}
```

Component Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index" 
    [class.mouseover]="mouseOvered[i]" 
    (mouseover)="mouseOvered[i]=true" 
    (mouseleave)="mouseOvered[i]=false">
</div>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeye6c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Pure css solution, based on your code:

```
div {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pavk6d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).