# inserting tag thru interpolation

Tags: json, angular

I want to show a large text, made of sentences, that is justified, and has line breaks at specific locations. These line breaks are of course not reelated to where sentences end. A sentence can start in the midle of a line, and continue into the next.

I have a **sentences.json** file with information about the text fragments ("sentences") of the full text

Lets say:

```
[
  {
  "line":1,
  "text": "Hello<br>",
  "time": "00:10"
  },
  {
  "line":2,
  "text": "How are you?",
  "time": "00:25"
  },
  {
  "line":3,
  "text": "Great and <br> you?",
  "time": "01:10"
  },
...]
```

This is imported into **sentence.component.ts** via

```
import * as data from '../sentences.json';
...
export class SentenceComponent implements OnInit {
  sentences: any = (data as any).default;
```

I want to show each sentence as a  so that I can change the background-color when hovered. And so that when clicked I can play audio from a specific location based on the "time" field of the sentence.

So in **sentence.component.html** I do

```
<span *ngFor="let sentence of sentences"
  [id]="sentence.line"
  [ngStyle]="hoveredID === sentence.line ? hoveredStyle : normalStyle"
  (mouseover) = "showHovered(sentence.line)"
  (mouseout) = "showNormal()"
  (click)="play(sentence.time)">
      {{sentence.text}}
</span>
```

Based on the answer to post ["How can I add a class to an element on hover?"] ([How can I add a class to an element on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633117/how-can-i-add-a-class-to-an-element-on-hover)) by Aurelien Giraud]

Now, all the spans are inside a div, because in **app.component.html** I have

```
<div>
    <app-sentence></app-sentence>
</div>
```

And the div has style (set in **app.component.css**)
`text-align: justify;`

Some "sentences" are supposed to have a line break inside of them, as they start in the middle of one line and continue on the next.
My attempt to have a `<br>` as part of the "text" didn't help. Because when I use `{{sentence.text}}` to enter the text inside the span, it doesn't generate a `<br>` tag, just shows the text `"<br>"` in the middle of the sentence.
Any ideas how to do this?
And what's the easiest way to play an audio/video file from a specific time when a certain sentence is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use the `innerHTML` property binding

Simply replace your code with this

```
<span *ngFor="let sentence of sentences"
  [id]="sentence.line"
  [ngStyle]="hoveredID === sentence.line ? hoveredStyle : normalStyle"
  (mouseover) = "showHovered(sentence.line)"
  (mouseout) = "showNormal()"
  (click)="play(sentence.time)"
  [innerHTML]="sentence.text">
</span>
```

then you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend this approach because it bypasses Angular built-in security. You'll notice the first section in the link is "Security Risk." You should make certain that you absolutely trust the content before rendering it this way.

If you have HTML as part of a string you want rendered, you need to use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer),

```
export class SentenceComponent {

    sentences: any = (data as any).default;
    unsafeSentences: string[] = [];

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

    ngOnInit() {
       sentences.forEach(sentence => {               
           this.unsafeSentences.push(
               sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sentence)
           );
       });
    }
}
```

Then you can use `innerHTML` to set the content:

```
<span *ngFor="let sentence of unsafeSentences"
  [id]="sentence.line"
  [ngStyle]="hoveredID === sentence.line ? hoveredStyle : normalStyle"
  (mouseover) = "showHovered(sentence.line)"
  (mouseout) = "showNormal()"
  (click)="play(sentence.time)"
  [innerHTML]="sentence">
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. They do the job.
But I noticed that my inserting `<br>` tags is not doing what I was hoping it would do, which is to simulate a "shift-Enter" on Word, that forces the line to justify

Comment: I got a "problem":
_Argument of type 'SafeHtml' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)_
And anyway, the `string` to be passed to HTML should be `sentence.text` 
Therefore I edited the code to:

`ngOnInit(): void { this.sentences.forEach((sentence: any) => {this.unsafeSentences.push(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sentence).toString());    });}`

But still that's not enough, even if it worked, which it didn't, because `unsafeSentences` would only contain the values of `"text"`, and I no longer have access to `"line"` and `"time"`